# use mutation result in another mutation in graphql playground

Tags: graphql

I have 2 graphql mutations : `mutation1` and `mutation2`.

`mutation2` uses `mutation1` result (field `id`).

I'd like to create a seed and then run it in graphql playground.
My issue is that i can't use the `id` field in `mutationResult` in my other mutation.
so - this line is an error : `id: mutationResult.id`

Is there a way to do this?

I know i can create a js script for this, or import apollo client, but i'd like to use gql seed file instead.

AND YES - i'm aware of this issue : https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/462

```
mutation {
    mutationResult: mutation1(
        params: {
            email: "test@gmail.com"
            name: "test"
        }
    ) {
        id
    }

    mutation2(
        params: {
            id: mutationResult.id // THIS IS AN ERROR
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: very old problem ... AFAIK the only solution is to use resolvers+context (shared object) ... save sth in 1st mutation, use in 2nd ... valid as mutations are always processed sequentially

Comment: thanks.. as i said, i'm aware of using proper code solutions, but i'm looking for another way